# XmlNodeList empty

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I got this xml.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <GetSelectedModels xmlns="http://www.something/">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <input xmlns="http://www.something/">
            <X_Models>
            <ListOfModels>
               <Model>
                  <ModelId>163</ModelId>
               </Model>             
            </ListOfModels>
         </X_Models>
         </input>
      </GetSelectedModels>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I post it in SoapUi and it reaches my web service I want to work with the nodes.

```
XmlDocument docRequest = new XmlDocument();
docRequest.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList models= docRequest.SelectNodes("X_Models/ListOfModels/Model");
```

models is 0 and the xml looks like this:

```
 <X_Modelsxmlns="http://www.something/">
    <ListOfModels>
       <Model>
          <ModelID>163</ModelID>
       </Model>             
    </ListOfModelss>
 </X_Models>
```

If I post my xml like this with an alias:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:net="http://www.something/" >
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <net:GetSelectedModels>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <net:input>
        <X_Models>
          <ListOfModels>
            <Model>
              <ModelId>163</ModelId>
            </Model>             
          </ListOfModels>
        </X_Models>
      </net:input>
    </net:GetSelectedModels>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then models will be 1 and the xml looks like this:

```
 <X_Models>
 <ListOfModels>
                    <Model>
                          <ModelID>163</ModelID>
                       </Model>             
                    </ListOfModelss>
                 </X_Models>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the `X_Models` node and all descendants are in the default namespace, which is `xmlns="http://www.something/"`.  In the second case there is no default namespace, so the `X_Models` tree are not in any namespace.

The documentation for [`XmlNode.SelectNodes Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies that default namespaces must be handled as follows:

> If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace URI is the empty namespace. If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still use the XmlNamespaceManager and add a prefix and namespace URI to it; otherwise, you will not get any nodes selected. For more information, see [Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Thus, given the XML you show at the start of your question (which doesn't quite match your code) you need to do:

```
    string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""no"" ?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" >
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <GetSelectedModels xmlns=""http://www.something/"">
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <input xmlns=""http://www.something/"">
                    <X_Models>
                    <ListOfModels>
                       <Model>
                          <ModelId>163</ModelId>
                       </Model>             
                    </ListOfModels>
                 </X_Models>
                 </input>
              </GetSelectedModels>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
        ";

    XmlDocument docRequest = new XmlDocument();
    docRequest.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(docRequest.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("models", "http://www.something/");
    ns.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

    XmlNodeList models = docRequest.SelectNodes("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/models:GetSelectedModels/models:input/models:X_Models/models:ListOfModels/models:Model", ns);
    Debug.Assert(models.Count == 1);
```

**Update**

If you really want to run queries on XML hierarchies that ignore namespaces and use only local names, then `SelectNodes` isn't going to do that out of the box.  You'll need a couple of extension methods like:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XmlElement> ChildElements(this IEnumerable<XmlElement> elements)
    {
        return elements.SelectMany(e => e.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XmlElement> OfLocalName(this IEnumerable<XmlElement> elements, string localName)
    {
        return elements.Where(e => e.LocalName == localName);
    }
}
```

And then you could do:

```
    string xml1 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""no"" ?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" >
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <GetSelectedModels xmlns=""http://www.something/"">
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <input xmlns=""http://www.something/"">
                    <X_Models>
                    <ListOfModels>
                       <Model>
                          <ModelId>163</ModelId>
                       </Model>             
                    </ListOfModels>
                 </X_Models>
                 </input>
              </GetSelectedModels>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
        ";

    string xml2 = @"
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:net=""http://www.something/"" >
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <net:GetSelectedModels>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <net:input>
                    <X_Models>
                    <ListOfModels>
                       <Model>
                          <ModelId>163</ModelId>
                       </Model>             
                    </ListOfModels>
                 </X_Models>
                 </net:input>
              </net:GetSelectedModels>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
        ";

    XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
    doc1.LoadXml(xml1);

    XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
    doc2.LoadXml(xml2);

    var ignoreNameSpaceModels1 = doc1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().OfLocalName("Body").ChildElements().OfLocalName("GetSelectedModels").ChildElements().OfLocalName("input").ChildElements().OfLocalName("X_Models").ToArray();
    var ignoreNameSpaceModels2 = doc2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().OfLocalName("Body").ChildElements().OfLocalName("GetSelectedModels").ChildElements().OfLocalName("input").ChildElements().OfLocalName("X_Models").ToArray();

    Debug.Assert(ignoreNameSpaceModels1.Length == 1 && ignoreNameSpaceModels2.Length == 1 && ignoreNameSpaceModels1[0].LocalName == "X_Models" && ignoreNameSpaceModels2[0].LocalName == "X_Models");
```

But this is like saying that `typeof(System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox) == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox)` because their [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the same.  That's because, the `xmlns="http://www.something/"` attribute in the following:

```
      <GetSelectedModels xmlns="http://www.something/">
          <!--child elements... -->
      </GetSelectedModels>
```

means "the element `GetSelectedModels` *and all child elements* belong in the namespace `http://www.something/` by default".  The `net:` prefix in

```
      <net:GetSelectedModels>
          <!--child elements... -->
      </net:GetSelectedModels>
```

merely means "the element `GetSelectedModels` belongs in the namespace `http://www.something/`".  It does not apply to child elements.  Recursive scoping is a special property of the [default namespace attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Comment: Thank you, but when I run this I still get 0 models. (If I run a XPath tester with the xml and the XPath it says that the namespace with prefix 'models' has not been declared.) I need the first example to work like the second but without alias.

Comment: @user3436977 - I've updated by answer to show the XML I used to test by code.  Your question shows several examples of XML and it's not clear exactly which one you are using to test.   Your final XML example is *not equivalent* to your first example because the `X_Models` subtrees are in different [XML namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Comment: If I run your example it will work. The thing is that when I post the xml to my web service (using soapui) the xml that comes as an input does not.

Comment: @user3436977 - My example is from your question.  Which example would you like to work?

Comment: The xml posted is the xml you used but the xml that I get in the web service that I need to work on is :<X_Modelsxmlns="http://www.something/">
            <ListOfModels>
               <Model>
                  <ModelID>163</ModelID>
               </Model>             
            </ListOfModelss>
         </X_Models>

Comment: @user3436977 - an xpath query that finds the `X_Models` subnodes in your first XML will not find the `X_Models` in your second XML sample, and vice versa, because they are in different namespaces.  In the first example, `X_Models` is really `http://www.something/,X_Models`.  In the latter case, it's just `X_Models`.  It's like having c# classes of the same name in two different CLR namespaces -- they actually aren't the same.

Comment: @user3436977 - answer updated - though I'm not sure I understand if you really want this.